# Python/Django filtering posts by its categories

Tags: python, django

Trying to filter the posts by using anchor tag in template

`<a href="{% url 'post_list' %}?school=SchoolA&category=CategoryA">GO to POSTS</a>`

url of above is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/?school=SchoolA&category=CategoryA`

For some reason this doesn't work and shows all posts no matter what category they have.

```
def post_list(request):
    school_slug = request.GET.get('school')
    category_slug = request.GET.get('category')

    posts = VideoPost.objects.all()

    if school_slug:
        posts.filter(school=school_slug)

    if category_slug:
        posts.filter(category=category_slug)

    posts = posts.order_by('-date_posted')

    return render(request, 'stories/browse.html', {'posts': posts})
```

This works somehow, but I can't filter the posts by either one of them only.

```
def post_list(request):
    school_slug = request.GET.get('school')
    category_slug = request.GET.get('category')

    posts = VideoPost.objects.all().filter(school=school_slug).filter(category=category_slug).order_by('-date_posted')

    return render(request, 'stories/browse.html', {'posts': posts})
```

It seems like there's some problem with if statement I assume, but I was not able to figure out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter(...)` does not modify the queryset it's called on, but returns a new one. So you have to reassign the result. Change

```
posts.filter(school=school_slug)
#  ...
posts.filter(category=category_slug)
```

to

```
posts = posts.filter(school=school_slug)
#  ...
posts = posts.filter(category=category_slug)
```

as you did you did it with the `.order_by` clause.

Comment: Oh.... it was that simple problem. Thanks a lot. it works now!

Answer (score 0):

In snippet 1:

```
    if school_slug:
        posts.filter(school=school_slug)

    if category_slug:
        posts.filter(category=category_slug)
```

This does not modify the `posts objects` as `filter` doesn't modify the original queryset. To fix this do the following:

```
    if school_slug:
        posts = posts.filter(school=school_slug)

    if category_slug:
        posts = posts.filter(category=category_slug)
```

or

In Sinppet 2:

```
posts = VideoPost.objects.all().filter(school=school_slug).filter(category=category_slug).order_by('-date_posted')
```

You are basically doing `category_slug and school_slug` in the above query set. To achieve `school_slug or category_slug` use [Q Filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)